# How to organize large-scale node apps

Tags: node.js, code-structure

**Scenario:**

I want to keep a clean structure, something like

```
/org/myapp/events/Events.js
/org/myapp/events/EventDispatcher.js
/org/myapp/game/Game.js
/org/myapp/characters/Worker.js
/org/myapp/characters/Warrior.js
/org/myapp/characters/Elite.js
etc etc
```

Currently I'm using `require`, and `module.exports`. It works but I'm curious as to what the community is doing outside of what I've been reading.

## Question:

What is a good way to organize a medium to large scale js application (30+ classes) while keeping a good handle on performance as well as overall organization?

**Current Implementation**

Based on my example above I would be doing

*Events.js*

```
class Events {
    ...
}

module.exports = Events;
```

Then for every class that uses `Events`

```
const Events = require("/org/myapp/events/Events.js");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing works fine, but personally I prefer to have each directory (e.g. `/org/myapp/events`) have an index.js file which exports the classes within the folder, like so:

```
// /org/myapp/events/index.js
module.exports = {
  EventDispatcher: require('./event-dispatcher.js')
}
```

Then consuming code can require the whole directory once and then access the parts as needed:

```
const events = require('./events');

const dispatcher = new events.EventDispatcher();
```